# Subscribe a bash script to run when MQTT message is received

Tags: linux, bash, mqtt, mosquitto

I would like to subscribe a bash script to run when an MQTT message arrives in a topic.

The basic `mosquitto_sub -d -t Topic -u user -p password` is not enough to do this.

For context I am using an esp8266 that needs to query an SQL database (look for an item) on a computer via MQTT protocol. The esp is already programmed to send the request in the payload and waits for a reply (item exist/not_exist).

Desired behavior:

- MQTT message arrives on desired topic
- message triggers a bash script
  (process_message.sh) to run and passes the payload to it as an
  argument.
- script interprets payload and sends a reply (already know
  how to do)

I am looking for any solutions that work and are simple to implement. Could be demon, bash magic, extra tool to install or convince me to use python/other code.

Comment: Should be quite simple with a **bash** loop that reads the output of `mosquitto_sub`. Can you click [edit] and add in your subscribe command and the first few received messages?

Comment: I _think_ you mean daemon? O\_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a little **bash** script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mosquitto_sub ... |
   while read payload ; do
      echo Received $payload
      ... process and produce response
      mosquitto_pub ... $response
   done
```

Save as `responder.sh`, and make it executable with:

```
chmod +x responder.sh
```

Then run it with:

```
./responder
```

Comment: Very creative, so this script just runs constantly and processes any output of mosquitto_sub. I am not sure how this would load my CPU, but should be very lightweight. Thanks